# Navigation in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Navigation in Xamarin forms: I have to navigate from page A to page B. In page A, I have written, `navigation.pushasync(new B)`. While I click `popasync()` from page B, it redirects me to page A. Which is correct.

Now I have another page navigation in A, which is to a page C. From C also I can proceed to B. But B's back button should always come back to A. 
While I am going from C to B, while clicking on back`(navigation.popasync())` I am reaching on C, instead of A. I don't want to create a new instance of A `( navigation.pushasync(A))`. How do I approach this problem?

In simple words, how do I pop 2 pages from navigation stack?

Comment: Format you question with paragraphs for users to read properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (SecondViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        break;
    }else if ([controller isKindOfClass:[ThirdViewController class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will face this issue when you use navigation.pushasync(new B)

I would better use Navigation.PushModalAsync(new B).

For more documentation please read [this:http://blog.adamkemp.com/2014/09/navigation-in-xamarinforms_2.html](http://blog.adamkemp.com/2014/09/navigation-in-xamarinforms_2.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Navigation object has a NavigationStack property which is basically the same as a browser history. It is a read only list. So you could do it like this.

```
if (Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack - 2].GetType() == typeof(A))
    Navigation.PopAsync();
Navigation.PopAsync();
```